# Why Is Inverse Quantization and Inverse Transform Taken Before Motion Estimation in H.264?

Tags: video

Here is the block diagram of the pipeline for the H.264 encoder (*Fundamentals of Multimedia by Ze-Nian Li, Mark S. Drew and Jiangchuan Liu*).
[image: H.264 encoding block diagram]

The feedback loop is used for motion estimation, but why is it taken **after** the transform and quantization steps? Why introduce and overhead from the inverse functions?
[image: H.264 edited encoding block diagram]

I know there's likely a very good reason for it, and this might sound like a stupid question, but I'd appreciate any answer that nudges me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77593568/781723

Answer (score 2):

Inverse quantization and inverse transform are how the encoder keeps track of which pixel-values the decoder will have in its buffer at any give point in time. If you skip that step, then you make the encoder a tiny bit faster, but the resulting compressed video will be much lower quality.

---

Let $S_i$ be the sequence of source/input frames. Let $\Delta_i$ be the lossy-compressed difference between each frame and the previous. Let $O_i$ be the decoded/output frames. Let $Q_i$ be the quantization noise. And for simplicity assume that the motion vectors are all zero.

In the normal encoder workflow, the encoder tries to set $\Delta_i = S_i - O_{i-1}$; but it can't do so exactly due to quantization; so it actually ends up with $\Delta_i = S_i - O_{i-1} + Q_i$.

The decoder adds up the deltas, and gets $O_i = O_{i-1} + \Delta_i = S_i + Q_i$. In particular, the difference between an output frame and the corresponding input frame is at most 1 quantizer unit, as it should be.

---

Now consider your proposed change to the encoder workflow. The encoder tries to set $\Delta_i = S_i - S_{i-1}$; but it can't do so exactly due to quantization; so it actually ends up with $\Delta_i = S_i - S_{i-1} + Q_i$. The encoder doesn't try to measure the value of $Q$ or adjust any future decisions to compensate, but quantization noise is still affecting the output frame just as much as before.

The decoder gets $O_1 = O_0 + \Delta_1 = S_1 + Q_1$; $O_2 = O_1 + \Delta_2 = S_2 + Q_1 + Q_2$; $O_i = S_i + \Sigma_{j=1}^i Q_j$. Each output frame is farther and farther from the corresponding input frame as time goes on. (Until the it's reset by an intra-frame, but those can be hundreds of frames apart, so that's still a lot of time to accumulate error.)

If we assume that quantization noise is uncorrelated, then the rate-of-growth of the error would be about $\sqrt i$ by the Law Of Large Numbers. If we make more realistic assumptions where noise can be correlated then it's even worse and might grow as fast as linear.

---

To be more concrete and worst-case, suppose we have a video that starts with an all-black frame (i.e. luma=0), and slowly fades to white (luma=255) over the course of the next 255 frames, at a rate of +1 luma per frame. And suppose the quantizer is 2.

The standard encoder records a delta whenever the next input frame differs from the previous encoded frame by 1 quantizer (i.e. +2 luma in this case). The result is a fade-in of +2 luma every 2 frames. Not quite as smooth as the input video, but basically matches the intended scene.

Your proposed encoder would look at each input frame; see that it's only 1 luma of difference from the previous frame, which is smaller than the quantizer and thus rounds to 0; so you'd fail to record any change at all. The end of the scene would still be showing black when it should be white.